# How to re-enable breaking on unhandled exception in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web?

Tags: web, visual-studio-2012, exception

I have disabled breaking on System.NullReferenceException in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web when that exception occured in debug mode.
How to enable it now? Debug/Exceptions menu item is missing.
I searched for System.NullReferenceException keys in registry, and value of State was always 16418 - same as other exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe (but can't verify right now) that those options are saved in the solution's suo (solution user options) file which is in the same directory as the solution (sln) file.

You can try to move the file to a different directory and see if your exception comes back. You'll loose any other customization you've done thought (start up project, breakpoints, watches, etc.)

Or you may try creating an extension and adding this functionality back to express :-)

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but after searching for a bit I have found a better solution for this problem. Tested in **Visual Studio 2019** and **Visual Studio 2022**.

Go to **Debug** > **Windows** > **Exception Settings**

[image: Instructions to view the Exception Settings Window]

Then in the Exception Settings window you want to click the **Restore the list to the default settings** button.

[image: The button to restore the default settings for exceptions]