# How to (re)enable breaking on exception in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

While doing pair-programming on an React project with Visual Studio Professional 2017, my partner was working on my machine and disabled some debugger option to see less warnings. I want to undo what he did, but he is not available any more, so that's why I am asking here. I remember faintly that he said something about disabling "some breaking".

I am sure it must be somewhere in the options window which appears after **Debug > Options** and on that popup somewhere under the entry **Debugging**. I attached a screenshot of **Debugging > General**. I already tried the toggling the 3rd check-box, but that did not do the trick.

[image: Screenshot of the popup window 'Debug > Options']

The interesting thing is that in the sub-window **Output** I used to see all those exceptions logged, but I do not see them anymore.

#### References

- [How to turn off warnings while debugging in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118284/how-to-turn-off-warnings-while-debugging-in-vs-code)
- [Enable a single warning in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151908/enable-a-single-warning-in-visual-studio)
- [How to re-enable breaking on unhandled exception in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098137/how-to-re-enable-breaking-on-unhandled-exception-in-visual-studio-2012-express-f)

Comment: @AlexF If you are talking about the **Error List** sub-window. Nothing has been showing here, what happened is that app stopped while running in debug-mode (like while doing breakpointing), the file with the unhandled exception showed up in VS, and a popup with the corresponding exception.

Comment: Can you check if any of these settings help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239325/how-to-find-reason-of-failed-build-without-any-error-or-warning

Comment: @mybrave If you are referring to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27425455/8330162 - I just tried that, this was not what I am after, this seems to increase the verbose level, but does not affect the breaking behavior, I think.

Comment: One more idea - do you mean breaking on exception? if yes then you can set that in Debug > Windows > Exception Settings - check the exceptions where you want to "Break when Thrown" or use Restore to default.